Storybook dynamic argTypes options
I have this type of story:
const meta: Meta<typeof forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, IButtonProps>> = {
    title: 'Atoms/Button',
    component: Button,
    argTypes: {
        size: args({ control: 'select', ...propCategory.appearance }),
        appearance: args({ control: 'select', ...propCategory.appearance }),
        text: args({ control: 'text', ...propCategory.content }),
        displayType: args({control: 'select', ...propCategory.appearance}),
        fullWidth: args({ control: 'boolean', ...propCategory.appearance }),
        iconAfter: args({ control: 'boolean', ...propCategory.appearance }),
        className: args({ control: 'false', ...propCategory.appearance }),
        disabled: args({ control: 'boolean', ...propCategory.states }),
        isLoading: args({ control: 'boolean', ...propCategory.states }),
        Icon: args({ control: 'false', ...propCategory.content }),
        name: args({ control: 'false', ...propCategory.functionality }),
        onClick: args({ control: 'false', ...propCategory.action })
    },
    args: {
        text: 'Button',
        appearance: 'primary',
        size: 'large',
        displayType: 'fill',
        isLoading: false
    }
};
export default meta;

const Template: FC<IButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});

I need to control options dynamically. For example, if appearance selected option is 'primary' the displayType options can only be ['fill'] and if appearance selected option is 'danger' the displayType options can be ['outline' , 'text'] and in this way for all my appearance options ['primary' | 'secondary' | 'danger' | 'success' | 'inverse' | 'transparent']
storybook version 7.6
Thank you in advance.

I saw your problems and I leave my opinion.
To dynamically control argTypes in Storybook, you can explore using the dependsOn feature or a custom function with the control property. This setup lets you adjust the available options based on another control’s value.
But, as of October 2023, Storybook doesn’t offer a direct way to handle dynamic options within argTypes. But don’t worry! You can achieve similar results by using decorators in your stories.

Thank you , but decorators don't change the options dynamically
